Change display style in expl3 multiplication
I have the same problem as mentioned here. The answer provided there is very helpful. I just don't know how to rewrite the code so that the decimal numbers are displayed with commas instead of ".". The code in question is as follows:

welcome! why did you delete the code you posted? did you mean to format it and removed it by mistake?

I would simply wrap all number outputs with the \num{...} command, from the siunitx package, and set
\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker={,}
}

Example:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    output-decimal-marker={,}
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\showmult}{mm}
 {
  \samuqg_showmult:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__samuqg_temp_tl
\tl_new:N \l__samuqg_factora_tl
\tl_new:N \l__samuqg_factorb_tl
\tl_new:N \l__samuqg_result_tl
\tl_new:N \l__samuqg_table_tl
\seq_new:N \l__samuqg_partial_products_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \samuqg_showmult:nn #1 #2
 {
  % remove leading zeros and the decimal point
  \tl_set:Nn \l__samuqg_factora_tl { #1 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__samuqg_factorb_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\A 0\.0*|\.) } { } \l__samuqg_factora_tl
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { (\A 0\.0*|\.) } { } \l__samuqg_factorb_tl
  \tl_reverse:N \l__samuqg_factorb_tl
  % compute the partial products
  \tl_clear:N \l__samuqg_padding_tl
  \seq_clear:N \l__samuqg_partial_products_seq
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \l__samuqg_factorb_tl
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__samuqg_partial_products_seq
     { \int_to_arabic:n { ##1 * \l__samuqg_factora_tl } \l__samuqg_padding_tl }
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__samuqg_padding_tl { \samuqg_padding: }
   }
  \seq_reverse:N \l__samuqg_partial_products_seq
  % do the multiplication
  \tl_set:Nx \l__samuqg_result_tl { \fp_eval:n { #1 * #2 } }
  % prepare the table
  \tl_set:Nn \l__samuqg_table_tl { \num{ #1 } \cdot \num{ #2 } \\ \hline }
  \tl_put_right:Nx \l__samuqg_table_tl
   { \seq_use:Nnnn \l__samuqg_partial_products_seq { \\ } { \\ } { \\ } }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__samuqg_table_tl { \\ \hline \num{ \l__samuqg_result_tl } }
  $\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
  \l__samuqg_table_tl
  \end{array}$
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \samuqg_padding: { \hphantom{0} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\showmult{0.436}{0.35}

\medskip

\showmult{1.2}{34}

\medskip

\showmult{1.222}{3.4}

\medskip

\showmult{0.022}{3.04}
\end{document}



Thank you! It works perfectly!
